# RFLAGS info and Radare?

Tags: debugging, radare2

Stepping through instructions I can see the result of `rflags` change,

```
rflags C1PSI
rflags 1PZI
```

Is there anything that expands this into the appropriate flags. I know `Z` is Zero-flag, and `P` is Parity, but I forget some of the more esoteric ones. And, what does the `1` stand for? What I would like is something like this

```
rflags 1P - [P]arity Flag ON
       k  - [k]whatever Flag On
       Z  - [Z]ero Flag On
       I  - [I]whatever Flag On
```

So I can find out what `k` and `I` are without going to wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the command `dr 1` to see every flag's value.

[image: dr 1]

Answer (score 1):

doesn't google give you that i see a million hits :( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register   CPAZSTID carry , parity , adjust , zero, sign , trap , interrup , direction

radare can tell what they mean

```
only interrupt flag cant be disabled 0x200
[0x77d570d8]> dr cf=0;dr pf=0 ;dr af=0;dr zf=0;dr sf=0;dr tf=0; dr df=0; dr of=0; dr=
 eflags I            esp 0x001efa90

[0x77d570d8]> dr cf=1;dr pf=0 ;dr af=0;dr zf=0;dr sf=0;dr tf=0; dr df=0; dr of=0; dr=
 eflags CI           esp 0x001efa90

[0x77d570d8]> dr cf=1;dr pf=1 ;dr af=0;dr zf=0;dr sf=0;dr tf=0; dr df=0; dr of=0; dr=
 eflags CPI          esp 0x001efa90

[0x77d570d8]> dr cf=1;dr pf=1 ;dr af=1;dr zf=0;dr sf=0;dr tf=0; dr df=0; dr of=0; dr=
 eflags CPAI         esp 0x001efa90

[0x77d570d8]> dr cf=1;dr pf=1 ;dr af=1;dr zf=1;dr sf=0;dr tf=0; dr df=0; dr of=0; dr=
 eflags CPAZI        esp 0x001efa90

[0x77d570d8]> dr cf=1;dr pf=1 ;dr af=1;dr zf=1;dr sf=1;dr tf=0; dr df=0; dr of=0; dr=
 eflags CPAZSI       esp 0x001efa90

[0x77d570d8]> dr cf=1;dr pf=1 ;dr af=1;dr zf=1;dr sf=1;dr tf=1; dr df=0; dr of=0; dr=
 eflags CPAZSTI      esp 0x001efa90

[0x77d570d8]> dr cf=1;dr pf=1 ;dr af=1;dr zf=1;dr sf=1;dr tf=1; dr df=1; dr of=0; dr=
 eflags CPAZSTID     esp 0x001efa90

[0x77d570d8]> dr cf=1;dr pf=1 ;dr af=1;dr zf=1;dr sf=1;dr tf=1; dr df=1; dr of=1; dr=
 eflags CPAZSTIDO    esp 0x001efa90
```

and radare can print the name of flags also

```
C:\> radare2 - -Q -c drl | tail -n 15
eflags
flags
cf
pf
af
zf
sf
tf
if
df
of
nt
rf
vm

C:\>
```

Comment: Yes, I found that with Google. However, most of the time when I use Google and Radare together, I find out later that I'm simply not using Radare right. I'll even upvote you -- Clearly I can open the Intel manual though. I half expect there to be a visual command that tells me what they all mean though.

Comment: radare can tell what which flag means

Comment: `dr` doesn't show me that, it just shows `rflags = 0x00000200`

Comment: it is dr= not plain dr dr= shows it in column and interpretes the flag values